# My Image is not getting rounded on all sides

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs

I'm try to round the borders of my image using border-radius and I'm not sure if overflow is affecting the image. Image 1: My current image. Image 2: What I am trying to get.
I'm working with React, HTML, node.js and CSS

```css
.about__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35% 50%;
  gap: 15%;
  --color-primary:#51B4FC;
  --container-width-lg: 70vw;
}

.container {
  width: var(--container-width-lg);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about__me {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent, var(--color-primary), transparent);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.about__me-image {
  border-radius: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  transition: var(--transition);
}
img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container about__container">
  <div class="about__me">
    <div class="about__me-image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1027/300/300" alt="About Image"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: This is what the image looks like]

[image: What I am aiming for]

Comment: Proper example, please. Even if I insert a placeholder image, it looks nothing like your screenshot. (Largely due to the missing variables, I suppose.)

Comment: @CBroe please do you have any idea of what variable it might be?

Comment: Please put a runnable snippet into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves. You will need to give values to those variables of course. Also can you explain how your grid has two columns but your pictures seem to show only one? It makes me feel that the code you have given is not the full story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try and put a class directly on the image, rather than styling the whole div. Also, if you're using React, perhaps changing class to className could work.